# Nextjs 13 conditionally render page/component depending on request method?

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I was wondering if there was any way to conditionally render a page depending on the request method. So let's say if you are registering a user the initial page with a get request would render a signup form and then on a post request you could render the results. Since all components now are by default server components you could just get the query from the url and perform your database actions directly from the component instead of having to have a separate api route. I don't see any way of getting the request method from `page.js`  and no way of rendering a component from `route.js`. Also you don't seem to be able to use a `route.js` and `page.js` in the same folder I get the following error:

```
Error [TypeError]: loaderTreeToFilter is not iterable
```

and

```
error TypeError: ComponentMod.renderToReadableStream is not a function
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:341:14)
```

So you apparently cant use the following. Which seems silly and doesn't seem to be stated anywhere in the documentation.

```
- register
  -page.js
  -route.js

// page.js
export default function Page() {
  return <h1>Page</h1>
}

// route.js
export function POST() {
    return NextResponse.json({ msg: 'Your at the post route' })
}
```

But like I said earlier there should be no reason to even have to call an api with Nextjs 13 components being server components by default. I should just be able to hit the url and do my server tasks right there just like you would with any other server side technology and then render a component based on that. But I don't see any way to get the request method from `page.js` and I don't see any way to render a component from `route.js`. I guess I could just look for query params in the url maybe?

Anyway am I missing something here or did Nextjs 13 completely miss the mark with this one. I guess data fetching on a server component is nice but it would be awesome if you could actually write server style code in these components without having to create extra api endpoints on your own server.

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to render a different screen after the user has sent (or after the completion of) a POST request?
You can consider redirecting the user to a different screen once you have the response from the API on the POST call. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: This would be better as a comment as it it not really an answer. Anyway I am trying to do what you can do with any server technology. If there is a GET request render a specific component and if there is a POST request render a specific component. With Nextjs 13 components being server components by default there should be no reason why I should need to make any api calls. I should be able to do all of my server logic in the component. But I don't see a way to distinguish between a GET and POST request in `page.js`

Comment: Let's assume you navigate to the login screen which is defined in the "page.js". Once you submit the form, ie you send a POST request to the backend and you receive a success response from the backend, you can make a call to ```redirect("/home")```

The GET and POST requests are sent to the server. GET request is to get some data from the database/filesystem and POST is to add some data. It has nothing to do with rendering the component. The component is an interface for making request/receiving the data. 
You just need to implement the logic to direct the user to the right screen/component

Comment: NextJS components being server components don't mean that they render components based on whether GET/POST methods. But, think of it as NextJS being intelligent enough to hide backend/api/sensitive information from leaking to the front end.
The way you would render the components is pretty similar to that in React. In React, you would send a request to the API, await its response and redirect the user to another screen(render another component if you will). You can follow similar approach here. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am aware that the components dont render based on GET and POST requests and I am well aware of how the process works. Just like I stated in my question I just want to know how to get the request method. Then I can conditionally render. You can get the headers with the `headers()` function so it seems like nextjs has the ability to give access to the request method they just aren't for some reason.

Comment: What if you create the route.js file in another folder say api/
So, you can have the backend requests made to routes "register/api" and from the GET/POST method you can do a redirect.

Something like this.
```
route.js

export async function GET(request: Request) {
  redirect('/users')
}
```

Is that what you are after?

Comment: fyi https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52427